# location service running on emulator does not work on real device

Tags: java, android-studio, permissions, location

I did a weather app in android studio. The app is working fine in the emulator. I created the apk to upload it to google play, tested it on a real phone, and accessed the location to show the weather in my app. Click the find my location button and it should find the location and bring the weather. but it doesn't work on real phones and app crashes. You can also add a city from the application and you can access the weather of the city, but it does not access the location for it. Adding city works fine. I don't know what is going on. It is working emulator completely What should I do? I am sharing my codes below. I have to solve this problem to upload my app to google play. By the way, I tested it on two real phones. Both worked the same. Sorry if my English is bad. Thank you for your response.

My main class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
String API_KEY;
String URL;

SQLiteDatabase database;

RecyclerView recyclerView ;

private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
List<Address> addresses;
String id ;


ActivityResultLauncher<String> permissionLauncher;
public LocationManager locationManager;
public LocationListener locationListener;
public Location location;
public LocationRequest locationRequest;
public Button btn_find_location;
public TextView txt_description;
public TextView txt_temperature;
public TextView txt_feels_like;
public TextView txt_wind;
public TextView txt_humadity;
public TextView txt_pressure;
public TextView txt_visibilty;
public TextView txt_dew_point;
public TextView txt_low_temp;
public TextView txt_high_temp;
public TextView txt_country;
public TextView txt_addressline;
ImageView img_weather;
public double Longitude;
public double Latitude;
public ProgressBar progressBar;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
forecast forecastclass ;

String cityname;



public void init() {


    database = openOrCreateDatabase("City",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS city(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,cityname VARCHAR)");
    img_weather = findViewById(R.id.img_dew_point);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    btn_find_location = findViewById(R.id.btn_find_location);
    txt_temperature = findViewById(R.id.txt_temperature);
    txt_feels_like = findViewById(R.id.txt_feels_like_temp);
    txt_wind = findViewById(R.id.txt_wind_speed);
    txt_humadity = findViewById(R.id.txt_humadity_ratio);
    txt_pressure = findViewById(R.id.txt_pressure_ratio);
    txt_visibilty = findViewById(R.id.txt_visibility_ratio);
    txt_dew_point = findViewById(R.id.txt_dew_point);
    txt_low_temp = findViewById(R.id.txt_low_temp);
    txt_high_temp = findViewById(R.id.txt_high_temp);
    txt_addressline = findViewById(R.id.txt_addressline);
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.MyToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();

    btn_set_location();

    registerLauncher();

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {

            Latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Longitude = location.getLongitude();


            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Latitude,Longitude,1);
                get_Data(Latitude,Longitude,addresses);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    get_cityname();


}

public void get_cityname(){

    try{
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int id = intent.getIntExtra("citId",0);
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM city WHERE id = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        int cityIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("cityname");


        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            cityname = cursor.getString(cityIx);
            System.out.println(cityname);
            get_Data_recyclerview(cityname);


        }
        cursor.close();

    }catch(Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("where id ? error");
    }
}

public void get_Data_recyclerview(String cityname) {

    Model model = new Model();
    //EXAMPLE URL
    //https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API%20key}
    
    API_KEY = "c29ecfafd4a70caad8fee38d6054bfc7";
    URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+cityname+"&appid="+API_KEY;
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("main");
                model.setTemperature(object.getString("temp"));
                model.setFeels_like(object.getString("feels_like"));
                model.setHumadity(object.getString("humidity"));
                model.setMax_temp(object.getString("temp_max"));
                model.setMin_temp(object.getString("temp_min"));
                model.setPressure(object.getString("pressure"));

                Double temperature = Double.parseDouble(model.getTemperature()) - 273.15;
                Double feels_like = Double.parseDouble(model.getFeels_like()) - 273.15;
                Double temp_max = Double.parseDouble(model.getMax_temp()) - 273.15;
                Double temp_min = Double.parseDouble(model.getMin_temp()) - 273.15;

                txt_temperature.setText(temperature.toString().substring(0, 4) + "°");
                txt_feels_like.setText(feels_like.toString().substring(0, 4) + "°");
                txt_high_temp.setText(temp_max.toString().substring(0, 4) + "°");
                txt_low_temp.setText(temp_min.toString().substring(0, 4) + "°");
                txt_humadity.setText("%" + model.getHumadity());
                txt_pressure.setText(model.getPressure() + "hPa");



              /*  JSONObject description = object_weather.getJSONObject(2);
                model.setDescription(description.getString("description"));*/


                //txt_city.setText(response.getString("name"));
                txt_visibilty.setText(response.getString("visibility") + "m");
                txt_addressline.setText(cityname);

                JSONObject object_wind = response.getJSONObject("wind");
                model.setWind_speed(object_wind.getString("speed"));
                txt_wind.setText(model.getWind_speed() + "km/h");

                // JSONObject object_sys = response.getJSONObject("sys");
                // model.setCountry(object_sys.getString("country"));
                JSONArray weather = response.getJSONArray("weather");
                JSONObject weatherObject = weather.getJSONObject(0);
                model.setMain(weatherObject.getString("description"));
                txt_dew_point.setText(model.getMain());
                model.setId(weatherObject.getString("id"));
                id = model.getId();
                load_weather_icon(id);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);

}



private void btn_set_location(){

    btn_find_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           requestLocation();

        }
    });
}

private void requestLocation(){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dlg.setTitle("Permission");
            dlg.setMessage("Permission Needed For GPS!");
            dlg.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                }
            }).create().show();

        }
        else{
            permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

    }
    else{
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,10000,3000,locationListener);
    }
}

private void registerLauncher(){
    permissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
                    if(result) {
                        //permission granted
                        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,10000,3000,locationListener);
                        }

                    } else {
                        //permission denied
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permisson needed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                }

            });
}

public void get_Data(double Latitude,double Longitude,List<Address> addresses) {

    Model model = new Model();
    //EXAMPLE URL
    //https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API%20key}
    //Balikesir 39.64917, 27.88611
    API_KEY = "c29ecfafd4a70caad8fee38d6054bfc7";
    URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + Latitude + "&lon=" + Longitude + "&appid=" + API_KEY;
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("main");
                model.setTemperature(object.getString("temp"));
                model.setFeels_like(object.getString("feels_like"));
                model.setHumadity(object.getString("humidity"));
                model.setMax_temp(object.getString("temp_max"));
                model.setMin_temp(object.getString("temp_min"));
                model.setPressure(object.getString("pressure"));

                Double temperature = Double.parseDouble(model.getTemperature()) - 273.15;
                Double feels_like = Double.parseDouble(model.getFeels_like()) - 273.15;
                Double temp_max = Double.parseDouble(model.getMax_temp()) - 273.15;
                Double temp_min = Double.parseDouble(model.getMin_temp()) - 273.15;

                txt_temperature.setText(temperature.toString().substring(0, 4) + "°");
                txt_feels_like.setText(feels_like.toString().substring(0, 4) + "°");
                txt_high_temp.setText(temp_max.toString().substring(0, 4) + "°");
                txt_low_temp.setText(temp_min.toString().substring(0, 4) + "°");
                txt_humadity.setText("%" + model.getHumadity());
                txt_pressure.setText(model.getPressure() + "hPa");



              /*  JSONObject description = object_weather.getJSONObject(2);
                model.setDescription(description.getString("description"));*/


                //txt_city.setText(response.getString("name"));
                txt_visibilty.setText(response.getString("visibility") + "m");
                txt_addressline.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));

                JSONObject object_wind = response.getJSONObject("wind");
                model.setWind_speed(object_wind.getString("speed"));
                txt_wind.setText(model.getWind_speed() + "km/h");

               // JSONObject object_sys = response.getJSONObject("sys");
               // model.setCountry(object_sys.getString("country"));
                JSONArray weather = response.getJSONArray("weather");
                JSONObject weatherObject = weather.getJSONObject(0);
                model.setMain(weatherObject.getString("description"));
                txt_dew_point.setText(model.getMain());
                model.setId(weatherObject.getString("id"));
                id = model.getId();
                load_weather_icon(id);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);

}

public void load_weather_icon(String id){

    int id1 = Integer.valueOf(id);

    if(id1>=200 && id1 <= 232){
        img_weather.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
    }
    else if(id1>=300 && id1<= 321){
        img_weather.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.showerrain);
    }
    else if(id1>=500 && id1<= 504){
        img_weather.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rain);
    }
    else if(id1 == 511){
        img_weather.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.snow);
    }
    else if(id1>=520 && id1<= 531){
        img_weather.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.showerrain);
    }
    else if(id1>=600 && id1<= 622){
        img_weather.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.snow);
    }
    else if(id1>=701 && id1<= 781){
        img_weather.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mist);
    }
    else if(id1 == 800 ){
        img_weather.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clearsky);
    }
    else if(id1 == 801){
        img_weather.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fewclouds);
    }
    else if(id1 == 802){
        img_weather.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scatteredclouds);
    }
    else if(id1 == 803){
        img_weather.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brokenclouds);
    }
    else if(id1 == 804){
        img_weather.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brokenclouds);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.addcity:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, addcity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        case R.id.showCities:
            Intent intentTocities = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cities.class);
            startActivity(intentTocities);
            return true;

        case R.id.show_5dayforecast:

                Double latitude = Latitude;
                Double longitude = Longitude;
                Intent intentToShow5DayForecast = new Intent(MainActivity.this,forecast.class);
                intentToShow5DayForecast.putExtra("lat",latitude);
                intentToShow5DayForecast.putExtra("long",longitude);
                startActivity(intentToShow5DayForecast);

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void AlertDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    dlg.setMessage("You can show cities after adding the city!");
    dlg.setTitle("WARNING");
    dlg.setIcon(R.drawable.warningicon);
    dlg.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"There are no city in the list ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).create().show();
}
   }
```

I requested location permissions in the main class.
I gave the necessary permissions such as Internet permission. I shared my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.HavaDurumuProjesi2"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name="com.enestigli.WeatherAPP.RecyclerView.cities" />
    <activity android:name="com.enestigli.WeatherAPP.Forecast.forecast" />
    <activity android:name="com.enestigli.WeatherAPP.AddCity.addcity" />
    <activity android:name="com.enestigli.WeatherAPP.Main.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**EDİT:**

The output of non-working API 24 emulator

[image]

[image]

As soon as I click find my location, I get the error app keeps stopping.

I do not encounter this error on the other real phone that I tested.
Could it be related to the phone version?

**EDIT 2:**

**location listener that I changed**

```
 locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {

            Latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Longitude = location.getLongitude();
            
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Latitude,Longitude,1);
                get_Data(Latitude,Longitude,addresses);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    };
```

I think just onStatusChange in is enough. I also created a new class and imported location listeners there and overrode methods like onlocationchanged. But it didn't work. by the way, onlocation changed in oncreat and I don't implement LocationListener in MainActivity. How Should I do this issue. ?

Comment: Enabling USB debugging on the real phone [(here how to do it)](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) and running the app, will print the output in Android Studio.
Then post the output here so we can help you

Comment: I found out that the phone I tested works apı 24 . I always tested apı 30 but real phone is apı 24 and I installed an emulator with api 24. By the way , it can't find the location because I'm trying to access the location in a closed area. it worked on a real phone when i tried it in an open area but this is real phone with api 24 i still get app stopped error. I am sharing output

Comment: I found the solution for this issue. It is necessary to override the onStatusChanged() method. I added onStatusChanged to my own code but I still get the same error. How should I do this error. I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: OnStatusChanged didnt work by the way.

Answer (score 0):

**I SOLVED MY ISSUE.**

Let's explain in detail. I used access fine location in my code. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION value allows you to get precise location information from services such as GPS.GPS location service was trying to find exact location because I was using access fine location but sometimes the GPS provider can't find your exact location.

The solution to this is to use network provider. Network provider if the device has an active GSM connection (if a SIM card is inserted and connected to the network), it allows the user to estimate the location from the base stations to which the Android device is connected. What is done here is to estimate the location of the user from the location information of these stations by sending the base station information to a central database. Although this system gives satisfactory results in areas with a large number of base stations (inner city areas) (40 meters deviation), the adequacy of the results decreases in rural areas where the number of base stations is low (1-2 km deviation). At the same time, this system may require an internet connection. In this way, you can access location services more easily by using a network provider instead of your Accessfine Location.Network provider consumes less battery than AccessFine location by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done on emulator by setting the priority as follows , otherwise getCurrentLocation won't trigger

```
 val Priority = Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
```